# Track down a Redis error event

Tags: redis

My Node.js app uses the node-redis npm module as its redis client. We are getting a error message on the client about a potential crash in our app, but cannot track it down. The redis client receives an error event, with an error object that offers a crash reason. Unfortunately, the string "user_id" is used so often in our code that it's hard to know where in the code this issue is happening. Any thoughts on how to get more insight?

```
var that = this;
this.redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    if ( !that.stopped ) {
        Logger.error("Redis Subscribe Client Error =" + err);
    }
});
```

Outputs:

```
Redis Subscribe Client Error =TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined. pid=3571
```

NPM Module: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Answer (score 0):

Display the stack with `err.stack`:

```
this.redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
   console.log(err.stack);
});
```